# Azure App Service plan stuck at 100% CPU

Tags: azure, cpu-usage, azure-web-apps, azure-app-services

[image: Azure App Service Plan stuck at 100% CPU]

Our Azure App Service Plan has been stuck at 100% for a few hours now. I've tried restarting the App Services on it, but to no avail. I think I need the whole VM hosting the App Service Plan behind the scenes to restart. Is there a way I can do this in Azure Portal? Or a way I can further investigate what's causing the high CPU usage?

Answer (score 0):

This blog shows you how to troubleshoot high CPU, basically you run a profile on the process that takes up CPU.
https://virtocommerce.com/blog/how-to-identify-the-cause-100

[image]

You can't reboot the hosts but you can move apps between app service plans so if you create another app service plan and move your apps you would "migrate" them to new hosts.

Comment: This link seems broken; do you know where I can find that same information. Thanks!